# How to force virtuoso sparql endpoint return full answer?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I want to query DBpedia and use Virtuoso. In some queries which their results are too much, it returns only part of the results. For example, in the query below, the predicate `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthplace` is missing. Is there any way to get all results either from Virtuoso or any other endpoint ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ( ?p   AS  ?outEdge ) 
                ( ?q   AS  ?inEdge  ) 
                ( ?px  AS  ?dest    ) 
                ( ?qx  AS  ?source  ) 
 WHERE  {
          { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/England>  ?p  ?px  . } 
          UNION
          { ?qx  ?q  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/England>  . } 
        }
```

Comment: How exactly are you performing your query?

Comment: There is for good reasons a internal limit. You can get all data by using LIMIT in combination with OFFSET, a pattern which is sometimes also called pagination via SPARQL.

Comment: thanks for helpful comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to query DBPeida and use virtuoso. In some queries which their results are too much it returns only part of the results for example in the below query the predicate http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthplace is missing. Is there anyway to get all results either from virtuoso or any other endpoint ?

While I don't detect anything malicious or mean-spirited in your question, you're essentially asking how circumvent DBpedia's defenses against intentional and unintentional denial of service attacks.  Internal limits help to ensure that too many resources aren't consumed by any particular query.  The right way to get all the results from a SPARQL query, if they aren't all returned at once, is to use **limit**, **offset**, and **order by**, and to use multiple queries.  E.g.,

```sql
#-- get first 10 results
select ... where ...
order by ?name
limit 10 offset 0
```

```sql
#-- get next 10 results
select ... where ...
order by ?name
limit 10 offset 10
```

```sql
#-- get more resuls
select ... where ...
order by ?name
limit 10 offset 20
```